# Two EU citizenships

Tags: dual-citizenship

Is it permissible, under a European legal framework, to hold two EU citizenships? Sometimes I read that it is possible, sometimes I read this is not possible because a person cannot be European "twice or more".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it is not possible to be European "twice or more," but that doesn't prevent the possession of multiple EU nationalities.  A person who possesses the nationality of an EU country is a citizen of the European Union, and a person who possesses the nationality of more than one EU country is also a citizen of the European Union.  This follows from [Article 20 of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Consolidated_version_of_the_Treaty_on_the_Functioning_of_the_European_Union/Part_Two:_Non-Discrimination_and_Citizenship_of_the_Union#Article_20):

> 1. Citizenship of the Union is hereby established. Every person holding the nationality of a Member State shall be a citizen of the Union. Citizenship of the Union shall be additional to and not replace national citizenship.

There is no unified EU nationality law; each member state determines the conditions for the acquisition and loss of its nationality.

Some EU countries have ratified the 1968 [Convention on the Reduction of Cases of Multiple Nationality and on Military Obligations in Cases of Multiple Nationality](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/043/signatures?p_auth=oppo5dZw), and others have not.  Germany ratified it and later denounced it.  Among other provisions, this convention specifies that a national of one participating state who acquires the nationality of another participating state should lose the first nationality.  But it does not seem to prohibit the simultaneous acquisition at birth of multiple nationalities, nor to require someone with multiple nationalities acquired at birth to renounce any nationality at any time.

There is also the 1997 [European Convention on Nationality](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/166/signatures?p_auth=oppo5dZw), also ratified by only a subset of EU countries.  This convention explicitly provides that states must allow certain cases of multiple nationality, and may allow other cases.  The mandatory cases are those of a person having multiple nationalities automatically from birth and of a person acquiring another nationality automatically through marriage (Art. 14(1)).

Therefore, the general answer to your question

> Is it permissible, under a European legal framework, to hold two EU citizenships?

is *yes.*

It is not, however, generally possible for every citizen of an EU country to acquire the nationality of another EU country without losing his or her original nationality.  That is not a feature of EU law, however, but of each country's domestic law.  The specific possibilities for any given person depend on the countries involved and on the manner in which each country's nationality has been acquired or will be acquired.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it permissible, under a European legal framework, to hold two EU citizenships?

Yes, it is possible. I know someone who does.

Basically, a person from country A and a person from country B fall in love and have issue.

If parents have their documents right, then children hold the nationality of both parents. Plain and simple.

Comment: Downvoter, please comment.  The answer is correct.

Comment: Don't mind. Voting down is a right. Thanks though.

Comment: Anyone born in Northern Ireland can, under the Belfast Agreement 1998 (sometimes called The Good Friday Agreement), hold either British or Irish nationality, or both.